# java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-data-jpa

I am relatively new in the world of Spring Boot and I have a problem with storing the data in database in my project. I have these entities: Flight - (flight number, gate, airport departure, airport arrival etc.), Passenger (passport number, name, surname etc.), Ticket( ticket number, passport_number(foreign key referencing Passenger table), flight_number(foreign key referencing Flight table)) and Luggage(id, ticket number(foreign key referencing Ticket table). When I want to make a reservation, first I want to save the data about the passenger, then save the data about the ticket(using the passport_number of the new passenger) and at the end to save the data about the luggage(also using the passport_number of the new passenger) and I want the whole process to be like a transaction. But I constantly get an error **java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
at java.base/java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:141) ~[na:na]** when I am saving the passenger. Here is the code. Any suggestions how can I solve this problem?  Here is the code from the controller where I am trying to save the data. Thank you so much.

```
  @PostMapping("/confirmTicket")
    @Transactional
    public String confirmTicket(HttpServletRequest req) {
        Passenger passenger = (Passenger) req.getSession().getAttribute("passenger");
        Flight flight = (Flight) req.getSession().getAttribute("flight");

        Passenger passengerNew = passengerService.save(passenger.getPassport_number(), passenger.getFirst_name(), passenger.getLast_name(),
                passenger.getEmail(), passenger.getAddress(), passenger.getPhone_number(), passenger.getAccount_number()).get();


        Ticket ticket = ticketService.save(Integer.parseInt(req.getSession().getAttribute("seat").toString()), flight.getPrice(),
                Class.valueOf(req.getSession().getAttribute("class").toString()), "", passengerNew, flight).get();


        luggageService.save(LuggageType.valueOf(req.getSession().getAttribute("luggage").toString()),
                Integer.parseInt(req.getSession().getAttribute("weight").toString()), ticket);

        return "redirect:/home";
    }
```

Comment: share the` passengerService.save(...)` implementation. Seems it returns empty `Optional`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xyz.get() method returns this error if xyz is null .
passengerService.save(....) is returning empty value ,check this service methos properly

Comment: `xyz.get() method returns this error if xyz is null`

That isn't accurate, I believe you meant to say something similar to the following:
`xyz.get() method returns this error if xyz is an empty Optional (isPresent is false)`

If xyz is null then you'd get a NullPointerException when calling xyz.anything()

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `get` on an Optional without first checking if the Optional is present. Calling `get` on an empty Optional [results in a NoSuchElementException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#get--)

Either call `isPresent` first or use `orElse` instead.

```
Optional<String> emptyOptional = Optional.ofNullable(null);
Optional<String> optional = Optional.of("Not empty");

emptyOptional.get(); // NoSuchElementException
optional.get(); // "Not empty"

emptyOptional.orElse(null); // null
optional.orElse(null); // "Not empty"

emptyOptional.orElse("default value"); // "default value"
optional.orElse("default value"); // "Not empty"

emptyOptional.isPresent(); // false
optional.isPresent(); // true
```

Comment: Yes, I know. But the question is why do i get empty value when I am savin the object in database.

Comment: That's impossible to tell based on the controller alone, please update the question with the PassengerService code